# How to divide one row into multiple rows?

Tags: linux, r, shell, awk, sed

The data format is like this(separated by tab):

```
A  1    2    3    5    6    9  
B  2    3    4    6    7    8 
C  5    5    7    5    6    9
```

**output:**

```
A  1 2 3
A  5 6 9
B  2 3 4
B  6 7 8
```

they are separated by tab. Is there any good way to do it?

Comment: Need some clarity. Are there always 7 columns like this in input and you want new line at 4th column?

Comment: Just a example, I have 180 columns and 220 rows.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F"\t" -v OFS="\t" '{print $1, $2, $3, $4"\n" $1, $5, $6, $7}' file
```

awk allows  you to reference fields in data by number, note that $1 gets used twice, and returns the **first** value from the line. Same for $2-$7. Fields are determined the the `FS` (field separator variable), in this case, `-F` is the Input FS, while OFS is the Output FS. Both are set to the tab char (`\t`).

**output**

```
A       1       2       3
A       5       6       9
B       2       3       4
B       6       7       8
C       5       5       7
C       5       6       9
```

IHTH

Comment: If a row with 180 numbers separated by tab are split every 6 numbers ?

Comment: Sorry, that would be a very different sort of answer and I'm going to bed.  In any case, you should post a separate question and indicate that 7 fields is only an example, and that you really need a more generic solution. However, Pluse-uno to you for sample data and required output. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a generic awk solution to add newline at a given column number:

```
awk -v n=3 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
       if ((i-2)%n == 0)
          printf (i>2||NR>1)?ORS $1:"" $1;
       printf OFS $i
    }
}
END {print ""}' file
A   1   2   3
A   5   6   9
B   2   3   4
B   6   7   8
C   5   5   7
C   5   6   9
```

Answer (score 1):

In `R`, after reading the data using `read.table/read.csv`,

```
 data.frame(Col1=rep(df1[,1],each=2),
           matrix(t(df1[-1]), ncol=3, byrow=TRUE))
 #   Col1 X1 X2 X3
 #1    A  1  2  3
 #2    A  5  6  9
 #3    B  2  3  4
 #4    B  6  7  8
 #5    C  5  5  7
 #6    C  5  6  9
```

If you have 180 columns and 220 rows,

```
m1 <- matrix(t(df2), ncol=6, byrow=TRUE)
m1[1:6,]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]    3   10    6    3    8    1
#[2,]    6    3    6    8    5    7
#[3,]   10    4    8    1    9    5
#[4,]   10    3    2    3    6    4
#[5,]    3    5    3    8    2    8
#[6,]    4    5    8    1    8    4

df2[1:2, 1:18]
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18
#1  3 10  6  3  8  1  6  3  6   8   5   7  10   4   8   1   9   5
#2  3  6  7 10  3  9  3  5  1   6   1   8  10   6   1   9   3   8
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c("A", "B", "C"), V2 = c(1L, 2L, 5L), 
V3 = c(2L, 
 3L, 5L), V4 = c(3L, 4L, 7L), V5 = c(5L, 6L, 5L), V6 = c(6L, 7L, 
6L), V7 = c(9L, 8L, 9L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", 
"V5", "V6", "V7"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

set.seed(24)
df2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:10, 180*220, 
           replace=TRUE), nrow=220))
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^((\S+)(\s+\S+){3})/&\n\2/' file
```

The `3` field can be changed to whatever field you require the break to occur.

Answer (score -1):

Using `sed`, to simply convert tabs into spaces:

```
sed -re "s/\t/ /g" input.txt
```

To convert only the tabs between numbers into spaces:

```
sed -re "s/([0-9])(\t)([0-9])/\1 \3/g" input.txt
```